# ggplot bar chart (geom_bar) to use start and end point from df

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have below `df` that I have 2 labels, A and B. And I want the bar chart for A to start from 0 to 2, for B to start from 3 to 6. How can I do that? If the `df` needs to be wrangled to do this, it's fine as well.

```
df <- data.frame(labels = c("A", "A", "B", "B"), values = c(0, 2, 3,6))

ggplot(df, aes(x = labels, y = values, fill = labels, colour = labels)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to make use of `geom_rect` which involves some data wrangling to get the data into the right shape:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(labels = c("A", "A", "B", "B"), values = c(0, 2, 3, 6))

df <- df %>% 
  group_by(labels) %>% 
  arrange(values) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = id, values_from = values) %>% 
  rename(ymin = 2, ymax = 3) %>% 
  mutate(xmin = as.numeric(factor(labels)) - .45,
         xmax = as.numeric(factor(labels)) + .45)

ggplot(df, aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, fill = labels, colour = labels)) + 
  geom_rect(stat = "identity") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:2, labels = c("A", "B"))
```

[image]